# Limit number of request for each destination

Tags: linux, proxy

I'm developing small service that download URLs from several computers. Each computer is accessing the Internet via same proxy computer.

I'm want to use the proxy server to limit the number of requests that sent for each destination (for maximum N request\seconds).

For example, lets define maximum border of 1 request per site in one second (1 request\second). Client A,B,C sends request in same time, for our proxy server, to download download 3 different pages from "cnn.com":

1. First incoming request will executed immediately, others will delayed.
2. Wait 1 second.
3. Take one of the delayed request and execute it.
4. Wait 1 second.
5. Execute the last delayed request.

I'm working with Linux (Ubuntu server).

There is proxy application that can do this job?

If the answer is "Yes", is this possible to solve this problem when there are several proxy servers?

Thank you!